# How to create a variable for column names

Tags: sql, variables, sql-update

I need to write an update statement that will replace all unwanted values to `NULL` in each field. I am using this update statement.

```
UPDATE TableName
SET    ColumnName = replace(ColumnName, 'what to replace', NULL)
WHERE  ColumnName = 'what to replace'
GO
```

I need to create a variable that will take the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` data and change the variable to each column name at a time and run the UPDATE statement on every column to replace the unwanted characters to `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a handy cursor (Assuming sql server):

```
DECLARE @Iterator varchar(55)
DECLARE @strSQL varchar(8000) -- for dynamic sql set then exec variable
DECLARE xyz CURSOR
FOR
--Select stuff to iterate over
SELECT c.name ColumnName
FROM sys.columns c INNER JOIN
     sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id INNER JOIN
     sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE t.name = 'table'   
OPEN xyz     
FETCH NEXT FROM xyz 
INTO @Iterator    
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN   
--Do stuff
SET @strSQL = '
            UPDATE TableName
            SET    '+@Iterator+' = NULL
            WHERE  '+@Iterator+' = ''junk''
            GO'
PRINT (@strSQL)    
    FETCH NEXT FROM xyz 
    INTO @Iterator     
END  
CLOSE xyz 
DEALLOCATE xyz 
GO
```

To actually execute this update you'd change PRINT(@strSQL) to EXEC(@strSQL),  PRINT first to make sure the statements read as you'd like them to.

Update: To loop through every table/column this would work to print out cursors for every table, but you can't execute the outer cursor.

```
DECLARE @Iterator varchar(55)
DECLARE @strSQL varchar(8000) -- for dynamic sql set then exec variable     
DECLARE xyz CURSOR
FOR
--Select stuff to iterate over
SELECT DISTINCT t.name TableName
FROM sys.tables t INNER JOIN
     sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
OPEN xyz    
FETCH NEXT FROM xyz 
INTO @Iterator    
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN       
--Do stuff
SET @strSQL = 'DECLARE @Iterator varchar(55)
                DECLARE @strSQL varchar(8000) -- for dynamic sql set then exec variable
                DECLARE xyz CURSOR
                FOR
                --Select stuff to iterate over
                SELECT c.name ColumnName
                FROM sys.columns c INNER JOIN
                     sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id INNER JOIN
                     sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
                WHERE t.name = '''+@Iterator+'''   
                OPEN xyz     
                FETCH NEXT FROM xyz 
                INTO @Iterator    
                WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                BEGIN   
                --Do stuff
                SET @strSQL = ''
                            UPDATE '+@Iterator+'
                            SET    ''+@Iterator+'' = NULL
                            WHERE  ''+@Iterator+'' = ''''junk''''
                            GO''
                PRINT (@strSQL)    
                    FETCH NEXT FROM xyz 
                    INTO @Iterator     
                END  
                CLOSE xyz 
                DEALLOCATE xyz 
                GO
'   
PRINT (@strSQL)   
    FETCH NEXT FROM xyz 
    INTO @Iterator     
END    
CLOSE xyz 
DEALLOCATE xyz 
GO
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly and It's exactly what I wanted. Can I also add something that would change the table names? so it would choose the table name then all the columns inside it and then take the next table and so forth.? would that be another cursor?

Comment: You could indeed nest this inside another cursor, it gets a little complex keeping track of dynamic sql nested inside cursors, but just use PRINT to keep track, if I have time I will whip that up.  Would it be every table in the db, or a subset of them?

Comment: Updated answer with version for every column in every table in the db.  Probably wise to use some WHERE criteria in the outer cursor 'WHERE t.name like '%something%'